# Examples of attoparsec in parsing binary file formats?

Tags: parsing, haskell, binary

Previously attoparsec was suggested to me for parsing complex binary file formats. While I can find examples of attoparsec parsing HTTP, which is essentially text based, I cannot find an example parsing actual binary, for example, a TCP packet, or image file, or mp3. Can someone post some code or pointer to some code which does this using attoparsec?

Answer (score 8):

There are few  or no examples of attoparsec for parsing binary formats, as parsec-style combinator parsing is mostly for text formats, not binary formats (though there's no good reason for this).

For straight binary parsing, see Data.Binary, examples include:

- [haskell-amqp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amqp)
- [haskell-bencode](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bencode)
- [haskell-ieee](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee)
- [haskell-dbus](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbus)
- [haskell-elf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/elf)
- [haskell-uuid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid)

and the examples in Real World Haskell.

The main example for attoparsec at the moment is an RFC2616 parser (HTTP).

- http://bitbucket.org/bos/attoparsec/src/tip/examples/Parsec_RFC2616.hs

Comment: Appreciate the "no good reason" comment because I don't see why a parser is more suitable for text and less for binary. Seems to me just as reasonable that a binary file can have multiple paths and need backtracking, etc.

Comment: Sure, it's just that attoparsec is so new, you'll be pushing out on your own. Just use Data.Binary like everyone else, and you'd be done by now :)

Comment: that link is for the Parsec version, the Attoparsec version is here: http://bitbucket.org/bos/attoparsec/src/tip/examples/RFC2616.hs

Comment: Combinatorrent has a attoparsec bitstream parser:

http://github.com/jlouis/combinatorrent/blob/master/src/Protocol/Wire.hs#L171

and the cereal-parser right next to it for your amusement.

Comment: @donStewart the links are broken, could you fix them? This post was really useful.